# The old and newVal on the watch doesn't seem to working

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I am working on dynamic data loading algorithm, in which there is state variable (VueX) `loadState` which manages the status of data whether is it **loading/loadinDone**

```
loadState: {
    filters:"LOADING_DONE"
    criteria:"LOADING"
    otherDependency:"LOADING_DONE"
}
```

there is `watch` on `loadState`,

```
...
computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
        'loadState',
        'project'
    ])
}
...

watch: {
    loadState: {
        deep: true,
        handler: function (newValue, oldValue) {
            Object.keys(newValue).forEach((key) => {
                console.log(key, " : " ,newValue[key], oldValue[key])
            });
        }
    }
}
```

this always same values like, 
`filters: LOADIN_DONE LOADING_DONE`

This is my mutation to update load state,

```
mutations: {
    [UPDATE_LOAD_STATE]: function (state, payload) {
        let temp = state.loadState;
        temp[payload.name] = payload.state;
        Vue.set(state, 'loadState', temp);
        // Vue.set(state.loadState, payload.name, payload.state);
    }
}
```

I have also take reference from : https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1086

but it is not working.

I do not understand how can I resolve that.

is there any best way to make waiting calls after all dependencies are loaded, we make certain data call.

I know approach of,

`<div v-if="isFilterLoaded"></div>`

but in My call, my dependencies can be dynamic, it may come from a database

Comment: Why using `mapGetters` for state ? you should use `mapState` instead

Comment: I already tried by in creating computed property by declaring : loadState = this.$store.state.loadState 

I thinks it is equivalaent to mapState, right ! ?

Answer (score 0):

From the warning in vue docs for [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch):

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

So you should handle this yourself by storing a copy of `oldValue` in the data property as:

```
    data() {
  oldLoadState: null
}
...

computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
        'loadState',
        'project'
    ])
}
...

created(){
  this.oldLoadState = this.loadState;
}
...
watch: {
    loadState: {
        deep: true,
        handler: function (newValue, oldValue) {
            Object.keys(newValue).forEach((key) => {
                console.log(key, " : " ,newValue[key], this.oldLoadState)
            });
            this.oldLoadState = newValue[key];
        }
    }
}
```

- we save the initial value of `loadState` in the data property `oldLoadState`
- reference this data property `oldLoadState` in your watcher to get the value of the `loadState` before mutation
- set the `oldLoadState` to watcher's `newValue` to keep the previous value saved

Answer (score 0):

Try to swap the entire object by a new one.

```
mutations: {
    [UPDATE_LOAD_STATE]: function (state, {name, state}) {
        this.loadState = Object.assign({}, state.loadState, {[name]: state});
    }
}
```